# Show hint in android system settings

Tags: android, android-settings

I open a system setting for input methods

```
Intent settingsIntent = new Intent("android.settings.INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS");
startActivity(settingsIntent);
```

and I want to show some hint, to help user set settings right. I saw this in another similar app:

Screen from another app

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to start setting app from your app.

```
  Intent settingIntent =new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS)
  startActivityForResult(settingIntent,55)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at snapshot, I can see 3 things,

1. You need to open `Preference Screen` with available virtual keyboards
2. It's a **`Footer`** & not a hint which you need to customize. 
   Ref. https://source.android.com/devices/tech/settings/settings-guidelines#footer
3. You need to fetch `Saved Preference Values` to show your Footer message along with it's preferred values. 
   Ref. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/use-saved-values#kotlin

Alternative to point no. 3, you can create `Custom Dialog` on `Preference Fragment` which shows the dialog at bottom.

Comment: I know how to add system settings to preference using intent. But it will be link to system settings screen and i can't customise it. What can i do with this?